# Playframework: how to decide if insert or update based on a field

Tags: java, mysql, playframework

I want  to save form record when `amount` equals to `0` and update it when `amount > 0`. But I don't know how to do it using Playframework. Here is my code:

Controllers method:

```
public static Result add() {
    Form<Store> taskData = form(Store.class);
    Form<Store> tasks = taskData.bindFromRequest();
    Store.recharge(tasks.get());
    return ok ("Stored successfully");
}
```

Models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "store")
public class Store extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    public int amount;

    public static Finder<Long, Store> find = new Finder(Long.class, Store.class);

    public static List<Store> all() {
        return find.all();
    }

    public static Store findById(Long id) {return (find.ref(id));}

    public static void add (Store data) {
        data.save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just check the `Store` model's amount and if it's > 0 then just call `data.update()` instead of `save()` ?  Maybe you can clarify some more.

Comment: Thanks to make my question claire.  I did this but does not work for me  :    
       `String amount = taskData.bindFromRequest().field("amount").value();
                    int am = Integer.parseInt(amount);

         if (am == 0 ){
 
Store.recharge(tasks.get());
return ok ("Stored successfully");

                    }
else if (am > 0){
Store.update(tasks.get());

          return ok("thaks for updated ");

}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you may not be using the Form functionality correctly, here's a complete working example:

Route

```
    POST    /test  @controllers.Application.test()
```

Controller:

```
    public Result test() {
        Form<Store> storeForm = Form.form(Store.class);
        Store store = storeForm.bindFromRequest().get();
        System.out.println(Json.toJson(store));

        if (store.getAmount() > 0) {
            //update
            System.out.println("perform update");
        } else {
            //save or recharge
            System.out.println("perform recharge");
        }
        return ok();
    }
```

Model

```
    public class Store {

        private Long id;
        private int amount;
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public int getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }
        public void setAmount(int amount) {
            this.amount = amount;
        }
    }
```

request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'id=12345&amount=0' "http://localhost:9000/test"
```

Comment: Thanks your post is helpful @ BatteryAcid

Comment: Please upvote or mark correct if it was helpful- thanks!